# Unable to generate property of type JSON using hibernate reverse engineering

Tags: java, json, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, mysql-5.7

I am using MySQL 5.7 inno DB and have a DB table with one column of type JSON. When i use hibernate reverse engineering to create POJOs, the entity java class is created for the table but the property type is Character. How do i get JSONObject or String type property for JSON column using hibernate reverse engineering ?

I am using MySQL5InnoDBDialect.

Comment: It's a bit unclear here, because of the tags. Are you asking for Hibernate (Java) or NHibernate (C#)?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion... I am asking for Hibernate Java.

Comment: Well, one way to do it, if you're using the `org.json.*` classes is using a JPA AttributeConverter. If you're using the `javax.json.*` classes from JSR-353 and Hibernate 5.1 or 5.2, then you can do me a favor and test if this also works with MySQL http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mopano/hibernate-json-contributor/1.0 . I'm think it should. You just have to add it as a dependency to your project.

Comment: I tried above solution.. however that did not work for me... POJOs are generating with Character type and not String or JsonObject type... I have to manually change the type to JsonObject everytime i run the hibernate tool... anyways thanks for taking time and providing inputs..

Comment: Generating with character type? You mean you're letting the table be generated by Hibernate? In that case, you should use the `@Column` annotation's `columnDefinition` value. I think the value to give it is `"json"`

Comment: No... I am using hibernate tool to generate java classes POJOs... so basically i am generating Java classes based on DB tables. So what happens it... DB column is JSON type (new format supported in mysql 5.7), but when i generate POJO (java class) using hibernate tool, the equivalent java property is Character. This is very strange as character will never hold json string.

Comment: Well, this has taught me some things I need to change to make it work in that direction, but then we hit the ClassLoading problem where we need the contributor to actually be loaded by whichever tool you're using to generate the classes (Eclipse / JBoss IDE / Ant). I hope to find time for it, but right now there is no automated way for hibernate-mapping to interpret `JSON` data type the way you need it.

Comment: Yes, your are correct... i also tried by changing the hibernate config xml and some other trial error methods... but it did not work... currently i am doing it manuallly